# Informix SELECT FIRST returning less rows

Tags: c#, odbc, informix

I am working on an import application to retrieve around 1 million records from an Informix database and bulk insert it in a MSSQL database. The query is simple: `SELECT * FROM <view_name>`. To fetch the data from Informix, I am using an ODBC reader and after executing the command I pass it directly to SQLBulkInsert.

The issue is here: There are times when all the data is retrieved. However there are times when the reader retrieves only up to the record #181 — and it is always up to this record when this issue happens. So I did a `SELECT SKIP 180 FIRST 2 * FROM <view_name>` to check that the data of these records are not corrupted or anything, but it seems that the data is OK. I also extended the connection timeout (even though this has no direct effect once the connection has been opened). This is a really annoying issue since it is happening only at times and it is always the #182 record that kind of stops the whole retrieval process.

Has anyone else had any similar issues? Or does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this?

This is the outline code I am using to retrieve the data via ODBC:

```
            OdbcCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = //sql statement;
            OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return reader;
```

Comment: See above. However I think this is an issue coming from the Informix database itself or perhaps the connection with the Informix. No exceptions are being logged / caught in the code - the reader either simply returns 181 records at times, or all the requested data

Comment: You mention SELECT FIRST in the subject, but then only reference it in the checking.  What is the SQL statement that you've coyly hidden as a comment?  If it has many columns listed, you can leave out most of them.  The erratic behaviour is undesirable, regardless (buggy, probably).  Which version of Informix database?  Which platform (o/s, version) is it running on? Which ODBC driver?

Comment: Could it be there's a data conversion error in record 182?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler obviously I specify the necessary columns that I want to return in my SELECT statement. The Informix database that I am trying to connect to is v10. I tried to work with both Informix ODBC driver 64 bit and the native driver 64-bit; and the issue still occurs. 

What I am noticing is that this issue often occurs after having been disconnected from the server for a period of time.

Comment: @FrankComputer I executed a SELECT SKIP 181 FIRST 1 to get the record 182 but the data seems fine - and yes 'FIRST' always return the same record (not just any random record that is.)

Answer (score 1):

That's might be in some cases. The problem might happen especially when you select from view and also when you select from join. The reason is: different access path's might not guaranty the sequence in which data is comes. It's highly recommended to perform very basic queries on views (like select * from) without where clause, first, skip and etc.